# Has there been any independent verification of the results from this Chinese nanotube study?

Tags: nanotechnology, carbon-family

[Watts up](https://wattsupwiththat.com/2018/10/26/space-race-game-changer-chinese-space-elevator-breakthrough/) referred to the [South China Morning Post](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/society/article/2170193/china-has-strongest-fibre-can-haul-160-elephants-and-space) in reporting that a Tsinghua University team led by Wei Fei claimed in 2018 to have manufactured carbon nanotube fibre with tensile strength of 80 gigapascals (corresponding to an engineering tensile strength of 43 GPa).

This would be a result with potentially very significant implications concerning the future of the human race and its relationship with space. Fiber of that strength might be suitable for the cable of a Terran orbital elevator (Estimates of required strength vary from 60-100 GPa.)

I've not yet investigated the difference between "tensile strength" and "engineering tensile strength", so it seems likely they're not quite strong enough, but if it's true, it's still an exciting result.

Has this result been verified or reproduced independently?

The study was published in Nature and is available in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325128963_Carbon_nanotube_bundles_with_tensile_strength_over_80_GPa), and a pretty nice plain language summary came out of [ArsTechnica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/05/forget-carbon-fiber-we-can-now-make-carbon-nanotube-fibers/).

Comment: I upvoted your question, but I feel it's unlikely to get any answer and might even be off-topic. Nanotubes are a very specialized topic area inside chemistry, and you are essentially asking us to hunt down references for you. And you haven't told us why you want the result to be verified independently. Are you also researching on nanotubes or is this just an idle curiosity?

Comment: This would be a result with potentially very significant implications concerning the future of the human race and its relationship with space. Fiber of that strength might be suitable for the cable of a Terran orbital elevator.

Comment: You should write that in the question, so that it's more understandable. For what it's worth, I think an orbital elevator would not be feasible/usable in at least the next 50 years, but who knows what will happen.

Comment: The entry on ResearchGate equally lists the publication's unique doi (https://doi.org/10.1038/s41565-018-0141-z) to be get to the landing page at the journal.  At present (July 27, 2021), the publisher knows there are 127 citations of this work, and a service like [scite_](https://scite.ai/reports/carbon-nanotube-bundles-with-tensile-1ZjVmrW?utm_campaign=plugin&utm_medium=plugin&utm_source=generic) 134.  Normally, you would read these (at least briefly) to check if their citation is about a method, a finding of interest mentioned earlier, if these support / extend / criticize the earlier work.